# iOS Safari Scrolling issue with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I'm currently working on a Web-App. In one case a user can pick some content and put it into a overview. Once this content is there he should be able to scroll through it.

This div has the correct parameters for all browsers except for the iOS Safari in one single case:

```
overflow-y:auto;
overflow-x:hidden;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
```

Only in one case this div is not scrollable on iOS. In all other cases with no modification of CSS / Javascript (the content is saved and reloaded via AJAX into the container) it works perfectly fine...

Is this a known issue on iOS Safari?

Thanks for your help

PS: I've also tried this workarround:

```
div .innerDiv {
    min-height:calc( 100% + 1px );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without your full code, who can say.

Try adding

```
position: relative;
```

to your div. Or another wrapper div around it